# How do I solve a diffusion equation with np.gradient?

Tags: python, spatial, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve this system of equations

```py
def df_dt(x, tau, L1, L2, c, q, h, alpha, lambda2, theta, epsilon, k1, k2, sigma, ki, kt, ke, P, d):
    dx = (k2/(ki+kt))*((c+c*L2)/(1+c*x[2]))*(x[2]+P)*( (L2/(1+L2))- ( (x[2]+d)/(x[2]+1)  )*x[0] )
    dy = ((alpha*q*sigma)/((1+alpha)*(ki+kt)))*(((((1/epsilon)*lambda2*theta*(1+x[2])**2) +(x[0]*x[2])**2)/ ((( (1+(alpha*theta))/(epsilon+(alpha*epsilon)))*(1+x[2])**2)+(x[0]*x[2])**2))-x[1])
    dz = ((ke/(ki+kt))*(((kt*x[1])/(ke*h))-x[2]))+((d)/(ki+kt)*np.gradient(x[2],2))
    return np.array([dx, dy, dz])
```

When I try to run, I have problem with the last equation "dz":

> "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Comment: `np.gradient` lets you numerically approximate a gradient. That's quite far from solving a PDE. Are you familiar with what the latter entails mathematically?

Comment: Yes I know, I don't intend to use finite elements, I just wanted to try this way to compare results.

Comment: What does "try this way" mean? Are you just trying to numerically approximate the gradient? That's not "solving the diffusion equation".

Comment: exactly, I'm just looking for a numerical approximation

Comment: You want to do something like MoL, "method-of-lines". Please note that every point of the space grid contributes to the state space, so that you at least will have to separate the flat input state vector into the 3 x,y,z components, which each are function tables over the space grid.

Comment: @JuanRubei: Of the gradient, right? I.e. not of the solution to the PDE.